# Explain this proof of Lemma about Generating equivalence relations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm reading Category Theory for the Sciences by Spivak available online at MIT. And I can't understand this proof.

[image]

In particular I have two questions.

> in other words ..., l is element of X x X.

If l is equivalence relation and equivalence relation is a subset of X x X shouldn't it be 'l is subset of X x X'? Is that a typo or what?

Next thing is this part.

> It is clearly reflexive, because R is

It is not so clear to me though. Because all that is said about R is that is a subset of X x X, which also mean that it is a some relation. But it could be non reflexive, right? Like for example 'is not equal' relation. It would be non reflexive, transitive and symmetric, right?

And even if R is reflexive, how does it proof that S is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve found two errors in the text. For your first question: yes, it should read $\ell\subseteq X\times X$. That error is probably a typo.

The other error is more substantial. There is nothing in the hypotheses of the lemma that ensures that $R$ is reflexive: for that we’d need to know that $R\supseteq\Delta_X=\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in X\}$. The simplest way to fix the argument is to replace $R$ by $R'=R\cup\Delta_X$. Any equivalence relation that contains $R$ must contain $R'$ and vice versa, so $L_{R'}=L_R$. $R'$ is reflexive, and the rest of the argument goes through as given.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I still don't understand the proof. First. the vice versa part. What is the opposite side of that? R' must contain any equivalence relation that contains R? Don't think so.

Comment: @user1685095: Any equivalence relation that contains $R'$ must contain $R$ (since $R\subseteq R'$).

Comment: Oh that, Yeah I see.

Comment: So am I understand this right? If S is pairs (x, y) that exist in every l, and S is superset of R, then if we take any pair (x', y') from R there would be pair (x, x) in S because any equivalence relation that contains R must contain R' which contains (x,x), right?

Comment: Also, just in case, Brian can you suggest a better book on category theory? Because I've just spent half a day figuring that out, thinking how stupid I am because I can't understand why R is reflexive etc.

Comment: @user1685095: You’re making it too complicated. If $x\in X$ and $\ell\in L_R$, then $\langle x,x\rangle\in\ell$ because $\ell$ is an equivalence relation and therefore reflexive. Thus, $\langle x,x\rangle\in S$.

Comment: @user1685095: I’m afraid that I can’t help with a book suggestion: I’ve never had any use for category theory, to be honest, so I have almost zero familiarity with books on the subject.